# Hamiltonian paths in 2-generated (Cayley) circulant digraphs. A counterexample?

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory

Circulant digraphs are Cayley digraphs of cyclic groups. My question refers to hamiltonian paths (not to hamiltonian cycles) in 2-generated circulant digraphs (not graphs).

There is a theorem by Holsztynski and Nathanson, as mentioned by W.Holsztynski and R.F.E Strube in ***Paths and circuits in finite groups (Discrete Mathematics 22, 1978)*** that says that *every finite abelian group and Hamiltonian group is sequential*. A group G is sequential (as they define) *if for every subset A of G generating G there is a complete A-Path*. A complete A-path is equivalent to a hamiltonian path. So what they are saying is that all generating sets of an abelian group (an hamiltonian group) has a hamiltonian path.

This same result is stated by Gallian in his algebra book (still there in 2010 edition) as follows: "*Let G be a finite abelian group, and let S be any non empty generating set for G. Then Cay(S:G) has a Hamiltonian path*".

To my knowledge this theorem is still accepted. Holsztynski and Nathanson has been revisited recently by Stowe (2017) and Gallian´s is mentioned in the last survey of these kind of problems (Lanel et all, 2019).These papers can be found easyly in a web search.

But it can be shown easyly (as the orders are low, reader can check by its own), that **6(1,3)** and **9(1,4)**, where 6 and 9 are the orders of the group (number of vertices ofthe digraphs) and 1 and 3 and 1 and 4 are respectively the jumps (i.e. the diferences that define the arcs in the circulant digraph) does not have hamiltonian paths. Anyone with some expertise in circulants can understand what this input (6(1,3) and 9(1,4)) means.

Aren´t those two cases, 6(1,3) and 9(1,4) counter examples to the mentioned theorem ?.

If they aren´t I can not see the reason they are not. In my view there is no doubt that 6(1,3) and 9(1,4) are circulant digraphs (i.e. Cayley digraphs of cyclic groups). I can give permutation generators for 6(1,3) and if needed i could give also for the case of order 9. Therefore they are Cayley digraphs of abelian groups and theorem should apply. So, if they aren´t what am I missing ?.

It should be noted that I am now researching hamiltonian traversal problem (i.e. cycles and paths) in these kind of digraphs (I am interested in generating all solutions for eah case) and these are the two first and smalest counterexamples I have found (if they are counterexamples at all, as I think they are). In fact so far I have only analysed to this respect cases of order 6, 8 and 9. There might be more...

P.s. I have seen that W. Holsztynski is a member of this Q&A platform. Maybe he can comment himself.

Comment: To clarify what I understand as a hamiltonian path. If we label the elements of the group (vertices of the digraphs with numbers from 0 to n-1 (i.e 0 to 5 and 0 to 8) and we start the traversal from the identity (vertex 0), then a hamiltonian path should end at vertex 1,3 or 4 but not in vertex 3 or 5 (that would count as hamiltonian cycles) in order 6 case, and end in vertex 1,2,3,4,6, or 7 but not in vertex 5 or 8 (that would count as hamiltonian cycles) in order 9 case. In fact it can be shown that a hamiltonian path must end in vertex 1 in order 6 case and in vertex 2 in order 9 case.

Comment: How does the Cayley digraph of $\mathbb Z/6$ with generating set $\{1,3\}$ not admit an Hamiltonian path? Can’t we just use the “jump” by 1 to get an Hamiltonian path (even cycle)?

Comment: Your answer clarify my doubts. In my view a path is a path not leading to a cycle, but if that is the standard view let it be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, when we talk about Hamiltonian path, we allow the first and last vertices of the path to be adjacent (in which case we can “upgrade” the Hamiltonian path into an Hamiltonian cycle).

I understand you don’t allow that, but this is not the standard definition, nor the definition used in the [Holsztynski-Strube paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X78900596) or the Lanel survey.

Note that there are smaller counter-examples if you want a Cayley digraph of an abelian group without any Hamiltonian path which cannot be upgraded into an Hamiltonian cycle, for instance take any abelian group $G$ with generating set $S=G\setminus\{0\}$.